# make error with gcc cross compilation tool in eclipse

Tags: c++, makefile, linaro

I am trying to cross compile for arm using iinaro in eclipse for C++ in windows

I have set the current toolchain using Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Toolchain Editor -> Current Toolchain to be cross GCC while the current builder is GNU MAke Builder

In my Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment, I have set the path to be C:\Linaro\bin where i installed my linaro and executable

but when i clicked build... there is build error "MAke: *** (test) error 127"

However when i changed my current builder to CDT Internal builder.. the error is gonne and it build successfully...

Can someone point out where i have gone wrong?

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Erro 127 usually means that make can not find a program that it needs to execute (such as gcc). Do you see any other error in the console view output prior to that one?

Comment: prior to that i have some gcc errror but i found out that in the toolchain prefix instead of "arm-linux-gnueabihf", i should have added "arm-linux-gnueabihf-"